# Drag and Drop пазлы

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop, project

пытаюсь двигать между Canvas части картинки ,мне выдаёт ошибку:Указанный элемент уже является логическим дочерним для другого элемента. Сначала отсоедините его.
Помогите,пожалуйста.

код для Drag and Drop

```
    private void DragImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.All);

    }


    private void DropImage(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Image imageControl = new Image();
        if ((e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) != null))
        {
            ImageSource image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) as ImageSource;
            imageControl = new Image() { Width = 100, Height = 100, Source = image };
        }
        else
        {
            if ((e.Data.GetData(typeof(Image)) != null))
            {
                Image image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Image)) as Image;
                imageControl = image;
                if (((Canvas)sender).Children.Contains(image))
                {
                    ((Canvas)sender).Children.Remove(image);
                }
            }
        }

        imageControl.MouseLeftButtonDown += imageControl_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        ((Canvas)sender).Children.Add(imageControl);

    }

    void imageControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(Image), image);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.All);

    }
```

---

```
<Style x:Key="ImagePlacement" TargetType="Canvas">
    <!-- <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="DragAndDrop"/> -->
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=placement}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
       <Setter.Value>
           <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Gold" GlowSize="5" />
       </Setter.Value>                
    </Setter>
    <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="DropImage" />
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="imageControl_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
</Style>
<Image Width="100"
    Height="100"
    AllowDrop="True"
    PreviewMouseDown="DragImage"
    Source="{Binding Pic, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Вот тут http://codepen.io/isc7/pen/yJaHE

Comment: _"Сначала отсоедините его"_ -- в DropImage выполняется это условие `if (((Canvas)sender).Children.Contains(image))`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не было ошибки надо удалять элемент после завершения `DragDrop.DoDragDrop`, примерно так:

```
var o = new DataObject(format, itm);
var res = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lst, o, DragDropEffects.All);
if (res == DragDropEffects.Move)
   (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Remove(itm);
```

Весь код примера - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477112/196972).