# puzzle drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop, wpf-canvas

Пытаюсь опустить в Canvas фрагмент изображения,но ничего не происходит.

код дроппа

```
private RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> _hatDrop;
public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> HatDrop
{
    get
    {
        if (_hatDrop == null)

            _hatDrop = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(hatDropExecute);

        return _hatDrop;
    }
}


private void hatDropExecute(DragEventArgs e)
{
    Fragment vm = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Fragment)) as Fragment;
    if (vm == null) return;
    _frag = vm;
    RaisePropertyChanged("HatImage");


}
```

код драга

```
private RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> _listBoxMouseDown;
public RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> ListBoxMouseDown
{
    get
    {
        if (_listBoxMouseDown == null)
            _listBoxMouseDown = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(executeListBoxMouseDown);

        return _listBoxMouseDown;
    }
}

private void executeListBoxMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(e.Source.GetType().ToString());

    ListBox list = e.Source as ListBox;

    if (list == null)
        return;

    if (list.SelectedItem == null)
        return;
    Fragment vm = list.SelectedItem as Fragment;

    if (vm == null)
        return;

    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(list, vm, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

биндинг драг

```
<ListBox x:Name="DragList" ItemsSource="{Binding Fragments}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ListBoxMouseDown}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                          AncestorType={x:Type Label}}}"
                           AllowDrop="True"
                           Source="{Binding Pic,
                                            Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HatMouseDown}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

биндинг дроппа

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ImagePlacement}"
                Tag="1">
    <Image Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Label}}}" />
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HatMouseDown}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>-->
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HatDrop}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

У Canvas надо установить Background, иначе он прозрачен для мыши.
Ниже пример drag'n'drop: между ListBox и Canvas перемещаются рисунки.
В ListBox выводятся рисунки. ListBoxItem'ы можно перетащить и сбросить над Canvas. При этом рисунок удаляется из ListBox и добавляется в Canvas.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="DragList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="200"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DragList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
            PreviewMouseMove="DragList_PreviewMouseMove">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" Source="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
            <Canvas AllowDrop="True"  Width="400" Height="300" Background="Transparent"
                Drop="Canvas_Drop"  DragEnter="Canvas_DragEnter">
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            var lst = new BindingList<BitmapImage>();
            lst.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Temp\Pic1.jpg")));
            lst.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Temp\Pic2.jpg")));
            this.DataContext = lst;
        }
        Point startPoint;
        string format = "image";
        void DragList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
        {
            startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }
        void DragList_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
            Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;
            if (Math.Abs(diff.X) <= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance
             && Math.Abs(diff.Y) <= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance) 
               return;
            var lst = sender as ListBox;
            var li = FindAnchestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
            if (li == null) return;
            var img = lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(li);
            var data = new DataObject(format, img);
            var res = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(li, data, DragDropEffects.All);
            if (res == DragDropEffects.Move)
                (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Remove(img);
        }
        void Canvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
            var img = new Image() {
                Source = e.Data.GetData(format) as BitmapImage,
                MaxHeight = 100,
                MaxWidth = 100 };
            var c = sender as Canvas;
            var p = e.GetPosition(c);
            Canvas.SetLeft(img, p.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(img, p.Y);
            c.Children.Insert(0, img);
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        void Canvas_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(format))
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject {
            do {
                if (current is T) return (T)current;
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            }
            while (current != null);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня уже задан Background в Style
я пытаюсь сделать с помощью RelayCommand,потому что мне надо оповестить мою ViewModel о том какой из моих фрагментов попадает в Canvas, и вытащить его индекс для проверки на правильность позиции.А как сделать это без помощи  RelayCommand, я не могу понять,если есть идеи,то я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @Артёс  у вас в коде executeListBoxMouseDown вызыватся?

Comment: Да,Drag работает

Comment: попробуйте в executeListBoxMouseDown cкопировать код из DragList_PreviewMouseMove, начиная со строки va lst =  sender as ... } а также копируйте Canvas_Drop и добавьте его вызов в xaml

Comment: я не  совсем понял.Я должен получать данные из своего класса,где хранится изображение и индекс,и + у меня используется bitmap, а не bitmapimage