# Drag & Drop из DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Разрабатываю приложение для работы с БД SQL Server на C#/WPF.

В приложении есть форма в которой справа DataGrid и посредством Drag&Drop осуществляется перетягивание элементов в левую часть. После перетягивания, свойство элемента `DataGridRow.IsEnabled` устанавливается в `false`, чтобы его невозможно было перетянуть дважды. И вот тут возникла проблема:

1. После перетягивания, случайным образом (на ширину приблизительно видимой области DataGrid) элементы получают то-же свойство `IsEnabled = false`, что и перемещаемый элемент.
2. Если промотать DataGrid вниз/вверх, элемент со свойством `IsEnabled = false`, снова становится доступным.

Подскажите, как этого можно избежать и что я делаю неверно?

А так-же, если не сложно, где можно почитать про такое поведение DataGrid (MSDN вроде весь перекопал)?

[image: Перетягиваем элемент]

[image: Случайно неактивные элементы]

**UPDATE 28.12.2015**

Исправил проблему воспользовавшись советом Stack с привязкой к источнику данных.

Comment: значения свойств у DataGridItem меняете сами? если да, то это неправильно. разные *Item - это контейнеры, они повторно используются. и контейнеры должны получать данные только от привязки к источнику данных.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, ввел в заблуждение. Не DataGridItem, а я меняю DataGridRow. Подправил в вопросе

Comment: DataGridRow это такой же контейнер. он подключен к источнику данных, т.е. есть binding. менять прямо свойства контейнера не надо. но можно только через источник данных. реализацию dragdrop посмотрите в моем ответе [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477112/196972)

Comment: Спасибо. Я в принципе так и предполагал, но решил посоветоваться с более опытными товарищами. Если не сложно, сделайте это отдельным ответом, я помечу как верный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridItem, DataGridRow - это контейнеры для данных. Если контейнер подключен к источнику данных, т.е. определен Binding, то WPF использует контейнеры повторно.
Это значит, что менять прямо свойства контейнера не надо, а надо менять сам источник данных. Пример реализации drag'n'drop посмотрите в моем ответе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477112/196972).